# Pequeña consulta SQL

Tags: mysql

**Consulta para Obtener Total Productos**

Buenas, estoy aquí por una consulta , no se si lo estoy realizando de la manera equivocada, pero bueno el problema es que si realizo la consulta para obtener el total de productos que tengo registrados en mi tabla "t_producto" que son 101 , pero al correr la consulta me sale que tengo 90 productos ! Pero no son 101

**Imagen del registro total de productos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Consulta MYSQL**

```
SELECT count(*) as productos from t_producto
```

**Resultado de Consulta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdón si estoy cometiendo una novatada. Gracias

Comment: Hola, si tu campo id_producto es "auto_incremet"(autoincrementable), posiblemente no este en orden es decir talvez la secuencia es algo como esto: 1 ,2,3,10,11,12,13,14,15,23,24,25,26. Eso suela pasar aveces, esa puede ser la razón.

Comment: No hay `101` productos, el `id_producto` del último producto cargado es `101`. Imagino que esa columna es `AUTO_INCREMENT`, y lo que puede haber pasado es que se han borrado algunos productos o si usas transacciones, debido a un error algunos no se crearon.

Comment: Parece correcto, tienes 90 productos. Y si haces `SELECT * from t_producto` ¿cuantas filas te salen?

Comment: Al hacer esa consulta `SELECT * from t_producto` me salen 101 productos

Comment: Tienen razón con respecto a que es `AUTO_INCREMENT` entonces y que en la primera fila algunos `id_producto` no siguen un orden !

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia,
Segun veo dices que son 101 por la secuencia del id_producto, podrias asegurarte primero que no se haya eliminado algun producto? podrias saberlo mostrando solo el campo id_producto y revisando que la secuencia se a consecutiva.

Comment: La secuencia no es consecutiva ! entonces no puedo hacer algo?

Comment: Ok, eso significa que el total de productos (registros en la tabla) entonces es 90, no veo inconveniente.